# Make a 3d array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database

I want to create a Array with multi-dimension arrays from a database. The Database has 3 tables, one for vehicle, one for damages and one for damagesPhotos.

**Table vehicle** has two columns **id** and **name**

**Table damages** has four columns **damagesID**, **vehicleID**, **damagesType** and **damagesDescription**.

**Table damagesPhotos** has three columns **damagesPhotoID** and **damagesID** and **damagesPhotoUrl**

I need to combine thoose three columns into an array, that looks like this:

```
$vehicle = array( 
   "id" => "somestring", 
   "name" => "somestring", 
   "damages" => array( 
       "damagesType" => "somestring", 
       "damagesDescription" => "somestring", 
          "photoOfDamages" => array( 
            "damagesPhotoUrl" => "somestring" 
          ) 
  ) 
);
```

My code looks like this, but is not working the right way.

```
$result = mysql_query( "SELECT * from vehicle v LEFT JOIN damages d ON v.id = d.vehicleID LEFT JOIN damagesPhotos p ON d.damagesID = p.damagesID WHERE d.damagesID = p.damagesID AND v.id = 1") or die(mysql_error());  

$rowsResult  = array();

while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $rowsResult  [] = $r;       
    }

mysql_free_result($result);

echo json_encode($rowsResult);
...
```

Comment: You do that by starting with vehicles only. The database is there to store the data, not that you copy *all* data from the database into your application. You only fetch specific data when the application needs that.

Comment: have you actually made an attempt at this yourself?

Comment: CKKiller, Yes I have but it is not working.

Comment: Then show us your code, doesn't matter if it doesn't work. When you've posted it please flag to re-open. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$vehicle = array(
    "id" => "somestring",
    "name" => "somestring",
    "damages" => array(
        "type" => "somestring",
        "location" => "somestring",
        "photo" => array(
            "imageurl" => "somestring"
        )
    )
);
```

For multiple vehicles, it might look more like this:

```
$vehicles = array(
    0 => array(  // you can omit the numeric index, I'm just using it for clarity
        "id" => "somestring",
        "name" => "somestring",
        "damages" => array(
            "type" => "somestring",
            "location" => "somestring",
            "photo" => array(
                "imageurl" => "somestring"
            )
        )
    ),
    1 => array(
        "id" => "somestring",
        "name" => "somestring",
        "damages" => array(
            "type" => "somestring",
            "location" => "somestring",
            "photo" => array(
                "imageurl" => "somestring"
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Yes, Thats exactly what I want.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this with an array, but you'd get far better structure by using domain objects and a data mapper to populate them.

```
class Vehicle
{
   private $id;
   private $name;
   private $damages; // collection of Damage objects
}

class Damage
{
  private $id;
  private $type;
  private $photos; // collection of photo objects
}

class Photo
{
  private $id;
  private $imageurl;
}
```

Your data mapper would use setter functions on the objects to populate the data when it is requested.

Comment: +1 for classes. Using hashes inside hashes inside hashes is a poor substitute for classes.  I wonder how people who code like that can ever maintain that stuff...

Comment: Usign classes is a good Idea, but I only need one car at the time, and the result is passed to my Objective-c code via JSON. So building classes is done in Objective-c. I just need to Join tables together to get all the data from the database with one call.

Comment: So why not access the database from Objective-C?

Comment: Because I can't connect to my database (not local) directly from objective-c, (Cocoa). I need ex. PHP to pass the data from mysql to my app(objective-c, Cocoa) via JSON.